# Simple Logic Python 3

Tags: python

Hey so I'm stuck on this question and not sure why my code isn't working. Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

> Write a function `alarm_clock(day, on_vacation)` that takes an int day
>   (encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat) and a boolean `on_vacation`
>   and returns a string of the form `"7:00"` indicating when the alarm
>   clock should ring. Weekdays, the alarm should be `"7:00"` and on the
>   weekend it should be `"10:00"`. Unless we are on vacation -- then on
>   weekdays it should be `"10:00"` and weekends it should be `"off"`.

For example:

- `print(alarm_clock(1, False))` gives `7:00`
- `print(alarm_clock(0, True))` gives `off`

I have:

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):

'''Alarm Clock'''

if day in range(1-6) and on_vacation is True:
    return '10:00'
elif day is 0 or 7 and on_vacation is True:
    return 'off'
elif day in range(1-6) and on_vacation is False:
    return '7:00'
elif day is 0 or 7 and on_vacation is False:
    return '10:00'
```

Comment: What output are you getting from your code?

Comment: Also why are you using the range 0 to 7 for what I presume is days of the week?

Comment: Because that's what we are told to use in the question :)

Comment: But 0 to 7 makes 8 days in a week, your question requested 0 to 6, which would be 7 days in the week. (0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday)

Comment: Indentation is wrong: the body of the function should be indented...

Answer (score 4):

```
if day in range(1-6) and on_vacation is True:
```

This should be

```
if day in range(1, 7) and on_vacation:
```

Otherwise, `range(1-6)` is indeed `range(-5)`.

Comment: `1 <= day <= 6` might be an even better test than `day in range(1, 7)`

Comment: @tobias_k it's more explicit and in Python 2.x doesn't require construction of a list for a linear scan - in 3.x - it's less important as there's "cleverer" membership testing... so six of one, half dozen of t'other

Answer (score 2):

If you provide output then it's easier to determine what exactly is off, but I do see that you used the wrong set of integers for your numbers. The full set you want to be able to pass the function is

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

You mistakenly tested for 7 in two of your lines, thinking of 7 days in the week. But an index starting at 0 will only go as far as 6 for days of the week since you're including the number 0. Also the syntax you used for range was wrong, it should be in the format **range(1,6)**

I think you expected it to be inclusive, ie.

```
range(1,6) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

but it would actually return

```
range(1,6) = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

because it goes from the first number provided up to the second but does *not* include it.

Here's how you could write your code:

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):
    '''Alarm Clock'''
    if on_vacation:
        if day in range(1,6):
            return '10:00'
        elif day in [0,6]:
            return 'off'
    else:
        if day in range(1,6):
            return '7:00'
        elif day in [0,6]:
            return '10:00'
```

I changed the conditional flow to try make it easier to understand and debug. It's usually better to branch more rather than having all four results based on both conditions.

Comment: `12==12 is True` evaluates `False` because these expressions are starting to evaluate the result from the last. `12 is True` => `False` (12 itself is neither true, nor false, only existence of 12 may evaluate true or false), `12==False` => `False`. You can check it by `(12 == (12 is True)) == (12 == 12 is True)` which will evaluate true. 

but `(12==12) is True` will evaluate `True`. And no matter in which part of memory it exists, always `True is True`.

Comment: You're right, I totally misunderstood that. I'm going to edit my answer to remove all that now because I noticed the number range is used wrong so that's probably the real culprit.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two outcomes if on vacation and two outcomes if you are not:

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):
    if on_vacation: # same as explicitly asking if on_vacation is True
        # if on vacation set it to off else set to weekday time
        return "off" if day in {0,6} else "10:00"
    # else not on vacation so 10:00 for wkend and 7 for weekday
    return "10:00" if day in {0, 6} else "07:00"
```

If on vacation you are either setting the alarm for 10 or off, if not on vacation the alarm is either 10 or 7. You might also want to check that the day is valid and output an appropriate message if the user enters a day outside the valid range.

You should also use `==` when checking equality, `is` only happens to work because small ints are cached in python, if you go outside that range you will see your test fail:

```
In [16]: day = 256
In [17]: day is 256
Out[17]: True
In [12]: day = 257    
In [13]: day is 257
Out[13]: False
In [22]: day =  257
In [23]: day ==  257
Out[23]: True
```

You won't encounter the issue using a range of ints from 0-6 but in general use `==`, `is` checks the identity of objects to see if in fact they are the same object, `==` checks the equality i.e do both object have equal values.

And just for fun, a different way to do it:

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):
    return {0: ["10:00", "off"], 6: ["10:00", "off"]}.get(day, ["07:00", "10:00"])[on_vacation]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a if/elif/else problem, your answer is good  changing `range(1-6)` by `range(1,7)`.

But if/elif/else is often difficult to read. Here week end days and on_vacation can be understood as cumulative bonus. Using list indexing you can also write:

```
def week_end(day): return (day%6 == 0) 
def alarm_clock(day,on_vacation):
    return ['7:00','10:00','off'][week_end(day) + on_vacation]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will be the expected solution:

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):
    if day in range(1,7) and on_vacation:
        print ('10:00')
    elif day is 0 or 7 and on_vacation is True:
        print ('off')
    elif day in range(1,7) and on_vacation is False:
        print ('7:00')
    elif day is 0 or 7 and on_vacation is False:
        print ('10:00')
alarm_clock(day_of_the_week,is_on_vacation)
```